# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to boot after upgrade to grub-efi-amd64

Tags: boot

I'm a company senior admin, we run a lot of Ubuntu 18.04 server on AMD. In the last 3-4 months we've had an issue with a few systems becoming unbootable during the application of OS upgrades from Ubuntu repositories.

We log all upgrades, and all show the following final two lines and then just hang. The systems are unresponsive. We cycle power and they fail to boot, put us at the grub> prompt.

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.14)

Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
```

I have troubleshooted and isolated the problem, the file /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg is missing the final line.

```
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

We can supply the info from grub> and reboot, and then fix the file -- but very annoying.

Did some searching, found similar reports here -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/efibootmgr/+bug/1855574

Our question: Can we just skip package updates for: grub-efi-amd64

Is there a fix?

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep grub` please. And `ls -al /boot/grub/` I'm just fishing.